# I run into problems when i add ".slice()" to the line of code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm new to vue.js.
I'm making a fast typing application.

Everything was as it should be, but when I wrote and ran this line of code, I got this error in the terminal:

> **INFO  Starting development server...
> 98% after emitting CopyPlugin
> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                            23:59:37
> This dependency was not found:
>
> - core-js/modules/es.array.slice.js in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/components/Main.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
>   To install it, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/es.array.slice.js
>   Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'**

As it told me to, I ran: `npm install --save core-js/modules/es.array.slice.js`

Then it looks like this:

> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall open
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\fast-typing\core-js\modules\es.array.slice.js/package.json
> npm ERR! errno -4058
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\fast-typing\core-js\modules\es.array.slice.js\package.json'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-06T21_06_50_092Z-debug.log

> Local ekranım ise şu şekilde :

> ./src/components/Main.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/components/Main.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js)
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.slice.js' in 'C:\Users\user\fast-typing\src\components'

Note: I tried `npm install --save core-js` and `npm install --save corejs@2` but the problem is not solved

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you're dealing with **version problems** of core-js package. You can look at package.json file and check "core-js" version. Let's update core-js package via npm.

Try:

```
npm install core-js@3.6.5
```

or

```
npm install core-js@3
```